# Ionic 3 with stripe and woocommerce-api

Tags: ionic-framework, stripe-payments, stripe.js

I am working on an Ionic 3 app with WooCommerce api. Currently I am using stripe to handle payments...Been able to get a card token from stripe after initial card check but I am lost in creating a charge from the card.

Piece of my code

> > component.html

```
<ion-content>
```

```
<div class="form-row">
  <div id="card-element">
    <!-- a Stripe Element will be inserted here. -->
  </div>

  <!-- Used to display Element errors -->
  <div id="card-errors" role="alert"></div>
</div>

<button ion-button block large>Make Payment</button>
```

> > component.ts

```
export class CardPage {
  stripe = Stripe('pk_test_**********');

  setupStripe() {
    let elements = this.stripe.elements();
    var style = {
      base: {
        color: '#32325d',
        lineHeight: '24px',
        fontFamily: '"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif',
        fontSmoothing: 'antialiased',
        fontSize: '16px',
        '::placeholder': {
        color: '#aab7c4'
      }
    },
    invalid: {
    color: '#fa755a',
    iconColor: '#fa755a'
  }
};

this.card = elements.create('card', { style: style });

this.card.mount('#card-element');

this.card.addEventListener('change', event => {
  var displayError = document.getElementById('card-errors');
  if (event.error) {
    displayError.textContent = event.error.message;
  } else {
    displayError.textContent = '';
  }
});

var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');

form.addEventListener('submit', event => {
  event.preventDefault();

  this.stripe.createToken(this.card).then(token => {

    if (token.error) {

      var errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
      errorElement.textContent = token.error.message;
    } else {

      console.log(token);
      this.stripeTokenHandler(token);
    }
  });
});
}

stripeTokenHandler(token) {
  var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
  var hiddenInput = document.createElement('input');
  hiddenInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
  hiddenInput.setAttribute('name', 'stripeToken');
  hiddenInput.setAttribute('value', token.id);
  form.appendChild(hiddenInput);

  // Submit the form

   form.onsubmit();
  }
 }
```

Using this my aim is to be able to charge the user's card the desired sum of products. Stripe says i should send the token to server but I am unable to figure out how to...pls how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with stripe api in ionic you can only get card token and verify card. you should send the card token to your backend server to charge the card holder.

`take card details -> obtain card token -> send to backend -> charge card`

follow this [link](https://stripe.com/docs/charges) for backend server charging.